# LEA assembly instruction

Tags: disassembly, assembly, x86

I am reading through the '*Practical Malware Analysis*' book and got to page 74 which says:

> `lea ebx, [eax*4+4]` is the functional equivalent of `ebx = (eax+1)* 5`
>   where `eax` is a number.

As of my understanding, `lea ebx, [eax*4 + 4]` should multiply `eax` value by 4, add 4 to it and then store it back in `ebx`, which is different than `(eax+1) * 5`.

Is that a typo? Or I got things wrong?

I think it should be: `ebx = (eax+1) * 4`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a typo. The instruction `lea ebx,[eax*4+4]` will set `ebx` to `4*eax+4` or `4*(eax+1)`.

I believe I found a revision online of that book which has:

> For example, it is common to see an instruction such as lea ebx, [eax*5+5], where eax is a number, rather than a memory address. This instruction is the functional equivalent of ebx = (eax+1)*5, ...

so it seems as though it was corrected at some point. Note that, technically, `lea ebx, [eax*5+5]` is really implemented as `lea ebx, [eax*4+eax+5]`.

Comment: The question is:  
lea ebx, [eax*4+4] is the same as ebx = (eax+1)*5